# Design patterns when no UI is needed

Tags: design-patterns

I'm familiar with the basics and concepts of a few design patterns (namely MVC, PM and the similar MVVM). Both of these (IMO) require a UI.

My project is pretty much run using Windows Services (a service runs, does something and updates a database - a SQL Agent Job runs and depending on the 'state' of a column in the table will then move it around/act upon it etc, another windows service is checking the table for another state which takes it out of the database and save it on the hard drive). OK, this isn't exactly what happens but the point is there is no UI - it's just the DAL and BLL (and SQL jobs).

So, my question is, for projects like this, are there any development patterns/guides to review or stick to? Or, are there situations where more than one pattern is required (eg, one for the code, one for the database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Non-UI related OO patterns might apply, depending on the situation.

Most of the design patterns have nothing to do with UI, and are simply named, common solutions to common OO problems: delegation, factory, visitor, composite, strategy, chain of responsibility, builder, proxy, observer, dependency injection, etc. etc.

Use them when appropriate.

Comment: That was easy! Thank you. And at the risk of doing no work myself, do you know of any which are good for Workflow style situations?

Comment: The state pattern might help, but the situation is too vague to give a definitive answer.